Ruby socket data transfer issue
I am developing a client server architecture in a ruby project where the client sends some data to the server , but when the server receives it, its size is much smaller.
The client has the following code:
def send_request(socket, action, data = {})
  request_data = [action] + data.map { |k, v| "#{k}:#{v}" }
  socket.puts(request_data.join(','))
end

player = {
  type: :FISHERMAN,
  name: "Andrew",
  party: $Trainer.party,
  speech: "Good game."
}

send_request(@server, 'player_data', { data: Marshal.dump(player) 
})

Here, the size of Marshal.dump(player) is 1842
Then the server creates a new thread per socket connected that starts with this:
begin
  loop do
    data = socket.gets
    break if data.nil?
    
    begin
      request_data = data.chomp.split(',')
      action = request_data[0]
      request = {}
      request_data[1..].each do |item|
        key, value = item.split(':', 2)
        request[key] = value
      end

      case action

The server processes the following case:
when 'player_data'
        data = request['data']

The point is to read the value of the key "data" sent in the request, which should be the Marshal data that the client sent.
But when it receives it, data.size is only 42, it is a string containing this: "\x04\b{\t:\ttype:\x0EFISHERMAN:\tnameI"\vAndrew\x06:\x06ET:". It should contain much more data.
Does anyone know what is happening? Thanks in advance.

Why not just use JSON instead? Using Marshal seems unessicarily complex and comes with some pretty serious security issues.

It's because your Marshal.dump data contains a newline character. If you read the data via socket.gets, it'll only return the first line.

FYI: data.chomp.split(',') is not safe at all. You can't just blindly join(",") and then later split(",") if there is any chance the data will contain ,. Use a real encoding format like JSON, or Marshal.dump your top-level object instead of just the nested object.

It's because your Marshal.dump output contains a newline character:
data = Marshal.dump(player)
#=> "\x04\b{\t:\ttype:\x0EFISHERMAN:\tnameI\"\vAndrew\x06:\x06ET:\npartyi\x01{:\vspeechI\"\x0FGood game.\x06;\bT"
#                                                                ^^
#                                                               here

... which will be recognized as a delimiter when using IO#gets:
require 'stringio'

StringIO.new(data).gets
#=> "\x04\b{\t:\ttype:\x0EFISHERMAN:\tnameI\"\vAndrew\x06:\x06ET:\n"

TCP sockets operate on binary streams. They don't know where a message starts or ends. You have to provide that information yourself. A common approach is to prepend the data by its own size. That way, the receiver knows in advance how many bytes to read and you don't have to reserve any bytes for delimiters (i.e. no escaping).
I'd also replace Ruby's Marshal format by JSON so you don't depend on a specific Ruby version (or on Ruby at all). On the client side you could use:
require 'json'

def send_request(socket, action, data = {})
  request_data = { action: action, data: data }
  json = request_data.to_json
  size = [json.bytesize].pack('L>')
  socket.write(size, json)
end

send_request(@server, 'player_data', player)

[json.bytesize].pack('L>') uses pack to convert the data size to a 32-bit unsigned integer (L) in little-endian byte order (>). (see packed data).
socket.write(size, json) then writes the 4-byte size value followed by the actual data.
On the server side you'd read the 4 bytes, decode it and then read that many bytes of data:
require 'json'

# ...

loop do
  size = socket.read(4).unpack1('L>')
  json = socket.read(size)
  request_data = JSON.parse(json, symbolize_names: true)

  case request_data[:action]
  when 'player_data'
    # do something with request_data[:data]
  end

  # ...
end

Note that the above works with any kind of data, it's not specific to JSON. If you want to use another serialization format, just replace the to_json / JSON.parse parts accordingly.

With JSON, you don't even need to prepend the size as simple JSON does not contain any (unescaped) newline characters. Thus, you can again use gets here.

@HolgerJust yes, indeed. I just wanted to provide a general approach that works regardless of the serialization format.

@Stefan thanks for your answer. Indeed the issue were the characters \n in the string. However, I can't load json in Rpg Maker XP, so that's why I'm using Marshal. I found a better way to encode the data and now I don't have issues related with that.
